# Smallest value of n for two algoritms with a certain running time

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms

If one algorithm has a running time of $100n^2$ and another of $2^n$; how can I find the smallest value of $n$ such that the former is faster than the latter?

I could do:
$100n^2 < 2^n$ then $\ln(100n^2) < n\ln(2)$ but how do I simplify the left side?

Comment: You try a few values of $n$, get some feeling for what's going on, try a few more values of $n$, and zero in on the answer.

Comment: An explicit form for the intersections of the two graphs is difficult to obtain.  An iterative/heuristic approach probably your best shot: 
[W|A link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10n%20%3D%202^%28n%2F2%29&t=ff3tb01)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best method could be to plot a rough graph of 100*n^2 and 2^n on the same pair of axes. Then see a probable point of intersection by some iterative method.